# Sql query, how to select the clients that has never stayed on a room that cost 5000?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the database

room(**room_id**, price)

client(**client_id**, name)

stayed(**StartDate**, EndDate, **room_id**, client_id)

I want to select all the clients' names that have never stayed in a room that has a price above 5000.
I tried this code:

```
select client.name
from client
inner join stayed on client.client_id = stayed.client_id
inner join room on stayed.room_id = room.room_id
Group by name
having room.price < 5000
```

It prints me the values of the clients that have stayed in a room < 5000 but some of them may have stayed on a room > 5000 at some other time.

Comment: `having max(room.price)<5000` should work.

Comment: Your query should generate an error in Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend `not exists` for this:

```
select c.name
from client c
where not exists (select 1
                  from stayed s join
                       room r
                       on s.room_id = r.room_id
                  where c.client_id = s.client_id and
                        r.price >= 500
                 );
```

This is almost a directly translation of your question.  Note:  If you attempt inner joins for this, then you will miss clients who have stayed in no rooms at all.  According to your question, you would miss these clients in the result set.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the aggregate function MAX in having:

```
select client.name from client inner join stayed
on client.client_id = stayed.client_id inner join
room on stayed.room_id= room.room_id
Group by name
having MAX(room.price) < 5000
```

Comment: I think you should group by client_id, as if 2 clients have the same name and one is above 5000 and the other is less than 5000 then the 2nd client wont show in this query!

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM client 
WHERE c.client_id NOT IN (
                          SELECT s.client_id 
                          FROM stayed s INNER JOIN room r 
                          ON s.room_id = r.room_id 
                          WHERE r.price > 5000)
```